# Drag and Drop in Android before 3.0?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, drag-and-drop

How can I do a drag and drop with Views in android without requiring Honeycomb or beyond OS?
The [Views support drag and drop functionalities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) but requires API level 11.

Comment: I'm sure he means drag and drop for view components. Malfist, I have faced with the same problem, I searched a lot, but didn't find a really effective solution. At last Ive developed my own d&d components. Search another questions about this problem. you can find a lot of good hints how to do this

Comment: Drag and drop views, specifically ImageViews

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Android Drag&Drop built-in framework requires API 11

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

If you need this feature on previuous API level, you have to implement it manually. I learned it from this guide/example:
http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/
(Many thanks to the author: Blahti)